# Can I have 2 .sln file in same path in VS 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have two different solutions in one git repository. One solution is in **folder A** and another is in a nested **folder B** under that **A** folder. Both are working fine. Now, due to the need to share some projects in both solutions, I want to have a clean approach so that development, build and deployments can be done without any problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3.

Can I have both .sln files in same path?
Have any one tried this, and what are the issues that could happen in future?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's fine to have two .sln files in same path/folder as long as they don't share the same name.

Please update us if you are having any trouble in specific. Thanks.